# How to intercept only base class methods with Castle.DynamicProxy

Tags: c#, system.reflection, castle-dynamicproxy

I have 2 classes, one for accessing the database and child class with caching. I can change the source code of both classes but there are many classes with different structure so I'm looking for a way to make generic solution that will help me to intercept only methods I marked with the `Attribute` or otherwise.

Here is an example

```
public class BaseClass
{
    [MyAttribute]
    public virtual MyEntity[] GetAll() {}
    [MyAttribute]
    public virtual MyEntity GetByKey(int key) {}
    [MyAttribute]
    public virtual void GetByName(string name) {}
}

public class ChildClass : BaseClass
{
    public override MyEntity GetByKey(int key) 
    {
        if(key > 100)
           return GetCachedEntity(key);
        return base.GetByKey(key);
    }
}

public class MyInterceptor : IInterceptor
{
    public void Intercept(IInvocation invocation)
    {
        // Here I can check any required conditions to decide on the way of processing
        var myCondition = invocation.Method.GetCustomAttributes(false).Any(a => a is MyAttribute);
        if(myCondition)
        {
            // extra logic for marked methods
        }

        invocation.Proceed();
    }
}

public static class MyProxyFactory
{
    private static readonly ProxyGenerator proxyGenerator = new ProxyGenerator();

    // here is my generic proxy factory which I want to use for creating proxies for ChildClass objects and another objects that contains similar logic
    public static TInterface CreateProxy<TInterface>(TInterface concreteObject)
        where TInterface : class
    {
        var proxy = proxyGenerator.CreateInterfaceProxyWithTarget(concreteObject, ProxyGenerationOptions.Default, new MyInterceptor());
        return proxy;
    }
}

[AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.Method, Inherited = false)]
public class MyAttribute : Attribute {}
```

I'm trying to use `invocation.Method.GetCustomAttributes()` for `myCondition` and mark only base class methods but the problem is that when the `ChildClass.GetByKey()` invokes the base class method it does not intercept with `MyInterceptor.Intercept()` method.

I can replace the inheritance with decomposition for this example but then I'll need to implement `GetAll` and `GetByName` methods in `ChildClass` and this solution will not be generic.

How can I change `ProxyGenerator` settings or `CreateProxy()` method to solve my problem?

```
var realObject = new ChildClass();
var proxyObject = MyProxyFactory.CreateProxy(realObject);

// extra logic should be executed
proxyObject.GetAll();

// extra logic should be executed
proxyObject.GetByKey(99);

// extra logic should not be executed
proxyObject.GetByKey(101);
```

Comment: maybe you should add some code that tests and proves what you're trying to say

Comment: @NSGaga I added the code at the end of my question. You can assume that extra logic in MyInterceptor contains `Console.WriteLine("query to database was executed")` then `proxyObject.GetByKey(99);` should write this message on console and `proxyObject.GetByKey(101);` should not.

Answer (score 4):

A `base.Method` call deliberately doesn't try to find any method overload that's further down the inheritance relationship than the base class of `this`. The proxy doesn't perform fancy magic, it overrides the method in a subclass and relies on the virtual call to reach the proxy rather than its base implementations. Or if it is a wrapping proxy, it only intercepts external calls - I don't know the details of your used proxy type.

So basically, you can't expect any sub-class magic to happen once you write `base.Method`. You will need to re-visit your design approach if you need interception within hierarchy-internal child-parent interaction.

Comment: I can describe the solution which can solve my problem and I was just hoping that `Castle.DynamicProxy` already has ready-made solution via settings for it. 
On proxy creation the `ProxyGenerator` can iterate the inheritance hierarchy and make proxy for each class in hierarchy. If we creating proxy with imaginary `ProxyGenerationOptions.ProxyAll` parameter for `class B : a` the final hierarchy will be `A -> ProxyA -> B -> ProxyB`. 
If we call `base.Foo()` in `B` object we will call `ProxyA.Foo()` method with the interception.

Comment: And I found that `ProxyGenerator` is not sealed then I can create my own generator based on it and implement required logic over existing methods.

Comment: @VadimMartynov This is very interesting... I didn't know you could actually rewrite a class in a way that its ancestor hierarchy changes (from `A -> B` to `A -> Proxy -> B`). To be honest it's beyond my knowledge how to achieve this result without a pre-compilation code rewriter so maybe we get another answer on this matter.

Comment: @VadimMartynov It is one thing to dynamically craft new types upon request. It is a completely different things to change already existing types such as B on the fly. For that, you would have to modify the CLR, so I am pretty sure this approach will not work. There is only one way to change an existing type in the CLR and that is by unloading its app domain and create a new app domain with the modified version of the type.